# Opentelemetry: javaagent jaeger exporter - add header

Tags: java, jaeger, open-telemetry

I have a problem with jaeger exporter, I have been looking for a solution for a long time and I understand that the solution is either not there or it has not been done yet.

**Is this at all possible to solve somehow?
How to add header to jaeger exporter?**

I am using javaagent and jaeger exporter. I want to add a header to the grpc request.

The documentation states that I can only configure 3 environment variables for the jaeger exporter.
https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java/blob/main/sdk-extensions/autoconfigure/README.md#jaeger-exporter

I can insert headers only if I use OTEL exporter(OTEL_EXPORTER_OTLP_HEADERS).

Accordingly, jaeger exporter ignores this variable. -> OTEL_EXPORTER_OTLP_HEADERS

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What about using [Opentelemetry Collector](https://opentelemetry.io/docs/collector/) to do this?

You can use the javaagent to forward to Opentelemetry Collector, which allows you to use OTEL_EXPORTER_OTLP_HEADERS.

Then, in turn, the collector can forward traces to your Jaeger instance

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I probably decided a little "in the forehead." Just started 2 additional collectors. They do not require much memory and resources. Collectors write to different indexes.

Comment: Is this header intended to be dynamic or static , the environment variable you have provided , adds a static header (which remains static throughout the application lifetime) , i had a similar query https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java-instrumentation/discussions/9767#discussioncomment-7438882 , it dosent seem like this feature works and it is not even available for gRPC , you would have to write a custom HTTP/GRPC sender and modify the send method to enable a dynamic header per request .

Comment: In case you want to add the header on during exporter on a collector you can consider these extensions : https://github.com/hickeyma/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/tree/db8a5b5a328e6299a8ab4e0ae02afb9b6bc65daf/extension/httpforwarder

https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/tree/main/extension/headerssetterextension